# Save dynamic data to two tables using relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `Students` and `Hobbies`. I've all details in one form but I want to save details to separate tables on submit. How can I achieve this?

My Student model

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Students extends Model {
protected $fillable = ['name', 'address'];

public function hobbies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Hobby::class);
}
}
```

Hobby model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Product;

class Hobby extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'entertainment', 'sports'
    ];

public function hobby()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public function save(Request $request, Student $student)
{
    $students= new Student;
                $students->name= request('name');
                $students->address= request('address');
                $students->save();
    if($students->save())
    {
        $hobbies= [];
        $images = $request->file('hob_img');
        $hob_desc = $request->hob_desc;

        foreach ($request->hob_name as $key => $hobby) {
            $hob_img = '';
            {
                $hob_img = uniqid() . '.' . $files[$key]->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $files[$key]->move(public_path('/assets/images/'), $hob_img);
            }
            $hobbies[] = [
                'hob_name' => $hobby,
                'hob_desc' => $hob_desc[$key],
                'hob_img' => $hob_img
            ];

        }     
        $hobbies[] = new Hobby;
                    $hobbies->hob_name = request('hob_name')[$key];
                    $hobbies->hob_desc= request('hob_desc')[$key];
                    $hobbies->hob_img = request($hob_img)[$key];
        $hobbies->save();

    }
}
```

But I cannot save it. It says `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Did you set `student_id` as `primary` in migration file? And you call `$students->save()` twice. Once inside the if is enough

Comment: There is a lot of problems in your code but to responde to your question add this `'student_id'=> $students->id` to your `$hobbies[]` variable !!

Comment: @Maraboc I did i also but still the same error! Is there any clean way than this?

Comment: ok what `$files` refers to ? why this $hobbies[] = new Hobby;??

Comment: $files is just a variable. $hobbies[]=new Hobby to save a new record of hobbies to `hobbies` table.

Comment: You have to take `student_id` as foreign to hobby model
then in your database `Student table` check there is any primary key or not and is it auto incremented or not.

Comment: Then for the relation you have to use first `students` class before using it,
then `return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);` here your class name is `Students` not `Student`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `insert` to save many records at onece :

```
public function save(Request $request, Student $student)
{
    $student= new Student;
    $student->name= request('name');
    $student->address= request('address');
    if($student->save())
    {
        $hobbies= [];
        $images = $request->file('hob_img');
        $hob_desc = $request->hob_desc;

        foreach ($request->hob_name as $key => $hobby) {
            $hob_img = '';

            $hob_img = uniqid() . '.' . $files[$key]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // $files i think it should be $images
            $files[$key]->move(public_path('/assets/images/'), $hob_img);

            $hobbies[] = [
                'hob_name' => $hobby,
                'hob_desc' => $hob_desc[$key],
                'hob_img' => $hob_img,
                'student_id'=> $student->id
            ];

        }
        Hobby::insert($hobbies); // useing Eloquent

        // Or you can use Query Builder 
        // DB::table('hobbies')->insert($hobbies);
    }
}
```